# How to quit a running batch?

Tags: c, windows, batch-file, winapi

Consider the following program:

```
main(){system("start /b batch.bat");}
```

I want to terminate the batch and any processes spawned by it sometime later in my program - any ideas?

Comment: use not *system* but `CreateProcessW` and assign new process to job object and finally call `TerminateJobObject`

Answer (score 1):

*I want to terminate the batch and any processes spawned by it sometime*

for this exist [Job Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/job-objects) :

> A job object allows groups of processes to be managed as a unit.
>
> To terminate all processes currently associated with a job object, use
> the [TerminateJobObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/jobapi2/nf-jobapi2-terminatejobobject) function.

```
if (HANDLE hJob = CreateJobObjectW(0, 0))
{
    WCHAR ApplicationName[MAX_PATH];
    if (GetEnvironmentVariableW(L"ComSpec", ApplicationName, RTL_NUMBER_OF(ApplicationName)))
    {
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
        STARTUPINFOW si = { sizeof(si) };
        if (CreateProcessW(ApplicationName, L"cmd /c <some path>/batch.bat", 
                0, 0, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED, 0, 0, &si, &pi))
        {
            if (AssignProcessToJobObject(hJob, pi.hProcess))
            {
                ResumeThread(pi.hThread);
            }
            else
            {
                TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, 0);
            }
            CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
            CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        }
    }

    // .. wait for something ...
    TerminateJobObject(hJob, 0);
    CloseHandle(hJob);
}
```

however new proceeses can be launched say via remote com calls (`StartService` for example) - formally from another process. this of course will be not in job and not terminated